# How to rename files with powershell if there are duplicate files?

Tags: powershell

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *_* | Foreach-Object -Process {
     $NewName = [Regex]::Match($_.Name,"^[^ _]*").Value +'.jpg'
     $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $NewName
 }
```

I have been using this code to rename files

For example, 569_SOM_TEST.jpg to 569
but if there is 569_TOB_TEST.jpg, It gives an error Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

I want it to make it 569-1.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent renaming clashes, you can put the below helper function at the top of your script:

```
function Rename-FileUnique {
    # Renames a file. If a file with that name already exists,
    # the function will create a unique filename by appending '(x)' after the
    # name, but before the extension. The 'x' is a numeric value.
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string]$Path,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [string]$NewName,

        [switch]$PassThru
    )
    # Throw a bit nicer error than with [ValidateScript({Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Leaf})]
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $Path -PathType Leaf)){
       Throw [System.IO.FileNotFoundException] "Rename-FileUnique: The file '$Path' could not be found."
    }

    # split the new filename into a basename and an extension variable
    $baseName  = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($NewName)
    $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($NewName)    # this includes the dot
    $folder    = Split-Path -Path $Path -Parent

    # get an array of all filenames (name only) of the files with a similar name already present in the folder
    $allFiles = @(Get-ChildItem $folder -Filter "$baseName*$extension" -File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)
    # for PowerShell version < 3.0 use this
    # $allFiles = @(Get-ChildItem $folder -Filter "$baseName*$extension" | Where-Object { !($_.PSIsContainer) } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)

    # construct the new filename / strip the path from the file name
    $NewName = $baseName + $extension   # or use $NewName = Split-Path $NewName -Leaf

    if ($allFiles.Count) {
        $count = 1
        while ($allFiles -contains $NewName) {
            $NewName = "{0}-{1}{2}" -f $baseName, $count++, $extension
        }
    }
    Write-Verbose "Renaming '$Path' to '$NewName'"
    Rename-Item -Path $Path -NewName $NewName -Force -PassThru:$PassThru
}
```

and use it like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*_*.jpg' | Foreach-Object {
    # create the proposed new filename
    $newName = '{0}.jpg' -f ($_.Name -split '_')[0]
    $_ | Rename-FileUnique -NewName $newName
 }
```

This will ensure that any proposed new filename gets a not already used index number attached to its basename.